# jQuery Mouseover Event is Duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm pretty new to this.  I'm trying to trigger a preview of a link via an iFrame, triggered by a hover (mouseover) event.

Here's the JSFiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/80so5jyL/

It works right the first time, but when I hover back and forth on a link more than once, it duplicates the display.  How can I ensure that there's only one iFrame popping up every time?

I tried unbinding the mouseover/mouseout events (that commented out line), and it prevents the duplication issue, but also doesn't allow me to display over that same link again, even after I've hovered out, or over a different link (which it still lets me do).

HTML:

```
<a class="tester" href="http://therainforestsite.com">Link Uno</a>
<a class="tester" href="http://www.example.com">Link Dos</a>
```

CSS:

```
.tester { display: block;
margin: 50px;
```

}`

JS (jQuery):

```
$("a").mouseover(function() {
    var thisURL = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(thisURL);
    var theCode = '<style>.preview {display:none;position:absolute;margin-left:0px;z-index:10;border:1px;solid #000;width:100px;height:100px;}</style><iframe class="preview" src="' + thisURL + '"></iframe>';
    $(this).append(theCode);
    $(this).children(".preview").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".preview").hide();
    //$(this).unbind('mouseover');
    return;
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` over `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because you are appending it to `this` everytime and thus it is getting duplicated. Use `.html` instead and also do not put it inside `this` i.e. `a` tag  when you use `html`. Keep it in a separate `element`, because when you use `.html` it will replace the contents and `a` tags `text` will be gone.

So I would suggest to use below `html`

```
<a href="http://therainforestsite.com">Some Link</a><br/><br/>
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example Link</a>
<p class="bigPreview"></p>
```

**CSS**

```
.bigPreview{
   display:none
}
```

and in `JS`

```
$("a").mouseover(function() {
    var thisURL = $(this).attr('href');
    var theCode = '<style>.preview {display:none;position:absolute;margin-left:0px;z-index:10;border:1px;solid #000;width:100px;height:100px;}</style><iframe class="preview" src="' + thisURL + '"></iframe>';
    $('.bigPreview').html(theCode).show(); //put it into .bigPreview and use .show on it
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('.bigPreview').html('').hide(); //clear its html and hide it
});
```